# Dart 2: Difference between Future<void> and Future<Null>

Tags: asynchronous, dart, future

Having an asynchronous function that doesn't return a value, what's the ideal return type `Future<Null>` or `Future<void>`?, or more specifically, what's the difference in using either? Both are legal, and in both cases the return value of the function is a `Future` that resolves to `null`. The following code prints `null` two times:

```
import 'dart:async';

Future<void> someAsync() async {}
Future<Null> otherAsync() async {}

main() {
    someAsync().then((v) => print(v));
    otherAsync().then((v) => print(v));
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The type `Null` only allows the value `null`

The type `void` allows values of any type, but communicates that the value shouldn't be used.

It's not yet clear to me how tools support will treat `void`. There will probably linter rules that hint or warn at using `void` values.

`Null` was used instead of `void` previously because `void` was only supported as return type of methods/functions.

Comment: Using `void` to accept any return value goes against the dart 2 policy of strong typing, so I guess that in the future returning a value with `Future<void>` won't be allowed, also `Null` doesn't make sense as a type so my guess is that it will disappear in the future. Nice answer, thanks.

Comment: No `void` will become much more common. `void` **allows** any return value, **but** callers will get a warning if they use the return value. Dart tries to get out of your way and if `void` would not allow any value, `() => foo()` would cause an error because of the implicit `return`. See also [this comment](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/32558#issuecomment-376115082) from eernstg