# void vs Null return types Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, void

I was looking at Flutter Boring Show and they used `Future<Null>` instead of `Future<void>` return type for a method. Then I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49410139/dart-2-difference-between-futurevoid-and-futurenull) question but what confuses me is that as the answer explained,

> The type void allows values of any type, but communicates that the value shouldn't be used.

I tried to check that in dart so I used the following code:

```
void main() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    print('hello ${i + 1}');

  }
  return 1;
}
```

And it gave me the following error:

`Error: Can't return a value from a void function. return 1;`

My question is that can you return anything if the function return type is void? Also what is the difference between Null & void as return types and which one is better to use if they have similar results?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this clear your doubts? https://medium.com/dartlang/future-void-vs-future-null-whats-the-difference-84a42d616e7d

Comment: @Shreya That explains everything. Thank you!